# MS Project 2013

Tags: microsoft-project

I have a finish to start link, the predecessor ends at 7:15am, I'm wanting to start the successor at 7:15 am currently MS Project always jumps to 8am, what do I need to do to force MS Project to start the Predecessor at 7:15am?

Answer (score 0):

Tasks can only be worked on during time set as working time in the calendar.  The default working time is 08:00 to 17:00.

Do you have a different calendar (task or resource) applied to the predecessor task or are you using elapsed duration?  Those are the only methods (other than manually scheduled tasks) to see a task end during non-working time.